# Issue with - grouping result based on time

Tags: mysql

I am novice in mysql. I was trying to get repeated record's count for particular key and for specific period of time, divided by total number of records available in that same period. Formula can look like count(col1 for particular period)/count(total no of records in col1 for particular period).

Also want to exclude col1 values which are not repeated. Table may look like

col1      date    
1       '2015-08-03'    
1       '2015-08-03'    
1       '2015-08-03'    
2       '2015-08-03'    
2       '2015-08-03'    
3       '2015-08-03'    
3       '2015-08-03'    
2       '2015-08-04'    
3       '2015-08-04'    
3       '2015-08-04'

Result will be

col1          Rate    
1           0.3 
2           0.3 
3           0.4

(corrected result for 2 )

Comment: Your calculation does make sense.  How does "1" get a value of 0.3 and "3" a value of 0.4?

Comment: frequency of 1 got divided by total number of col1 values during that period i.e. 3/10 ... same for others

Comment: Yes.. Krishnat that is right what i'm trying to evaluate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT col1, count(col1)/total 
FROM table1 ,(SELECT count(*) as total from table1 
WHERE date between '2015-08-03' and '2015-08-04'
 ) as temp 
WHERE date between '2015-08-03' and '2015-08-04' 
GROUP BY col1 
HAVING count(col1)>1
```

Comment: I tried with equivalent query in my database.. and it's giving expected result.. thanks Krishnat!